# Unusual array with key value NaN property, containing more arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, types

I have an unusual Javascript array with a length of 0, but if I expand the array I can see it contains multiple nested arrays with the same property, and eventually an Array containing an object.  I've never seen this type of array / object before.

This is a sudo code version (as far I can read it):

```
[NaN: [{foo:'barr'}]]
```

But constructing an object like that would cause an error. Can anyone explain what it is?

This is a screen shot of what it looks like console logged in Chrome:

[image]

And console logged in Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Nina Scholz answered it perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, you have 'NaN' as key, which is possible (arrays are objects), because you may have calculated the index, which goes wrong.

```js
var array = [];

array['x' * 3] = 'value'; // index/key is NaN
console.log(array);
console.log(array.NaN);
```

Comment: Oh I see, that's interesting, I've never seen that done before.  Thanks!

Comment: Just out of interest, why if I put `[NaN: [{foo:'bar'}]]` into my console, it says: `uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`.  It's a valid object so it should just print it and let me interact with it